# Unterschied zwischen "Abzeichen" und "Plakette"

Tags: difference

> **Plakette**- *kleines, flaches, meist rundes oder eckiges Schildchen zum Anstecken oder Aufkleben, das mit einer Inschrift oder figürlichen Darstellung versehen ist*
>
> **Abzeichen**- *Plakette*

Quelle: Duden

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern "Abzeichen" und "Plakette"?

Comment: Ein Abzeichen kann die Form einer Plakette haben, es kann aber auch nur eine Ziernaht oder Stickerei auf der Kleidung sein. Irgendwas leicht Wiedererkennbares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Einer der auffallendsten Unterschiede ist das Material aus dem beide gefertigt werden.

---

### Plakette

Eine Plakette ist, der Bedeutung des französischen Herkunftswortes (*plaquette*) nach, eine kleine Platte. Daher versteht man unter einer Plakette meist etwas, das aus Metall ist. Es gibt aber auch haltbare Aufkleber aus Kunststoff, die zum Aufkleben auf nicht-elastischen Flächen (z.B. Glas, Blech) gedacht sind.

Der Zweck einer Plakette ist, eine darauf angebrachte Aufschrift sichtbar zu machen (z.B. Prüfplakette bei Kraftfahrzeugen)

---

### Abzeichen

Ein Abzeichen ist einer Plakette sehr ähnlich, kann aber auch aus Stoff sein, um es auf einem Kleidungsstück (T-Shirt, Jacke) aufzunähen. Beispielsweise machen viele Schüler Schwimmkurse, und nach dem Ablegen einer Prüfung bekommen sie ein Abzeichen, das man auf die Badehose aufnähen kann (z.B. »Seepferdchen«)